# How to sort files by name using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I would like to sort all files by date with a Shell script.

For example, in `/Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/` there are the files `M1.h`, `A2.h` and `F4.h`.

Each file has a different time. How do I sort all these files from oldest to current by date and time?

Currently I have a rename script:

```
cd /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/ 
n=1
for file in *.jpg;
do 
  echo $file prefix=M file_name=M$n.jpg 
  echo $file_name n=$(( $n+1 ))
  mv $file $file_name 
done
```

The first time I run script the JPG files will be `M1.jpg`, `M2.jpg` and `M3.jpg` but if I add a new file named `A1.jpg` to this directory and run the script again, `M1.jpg`, `M2.jpg` and `M3.jpg` will be replaced by `M4.jpg` (before running the script, this file was named `A1.jpg`) because the first letter is `A` and came before `M`.

I would like to get `M1`, `M2`, `M3` and `M4.jpg`.

Comment: The question changed mid-stream. It started out sorting `*.h` files but the commentary and code reflect sorting `*.jpg` files. Consistency is important when asking questions.

Answer (score 10):

The `ls` command can easily sort by last modified time:

```
$ ls -1t /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test
```

To reverse the sort, include the `-r` option:

```
$ ls -1tr /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test
```

Including the `1` tells `ls` to output one file per line without extra metadata (like the length, modification time, etc), which is often what you need in a shell script if you need to send the list to other commands for further processing.

Comment: This sorts from new to old - this is not what was ask.

Comment: Then use the `-r` flag as appropriate to change the order.

Answer (score 3):

(Completely new because the question changed)

Try this:

```
cd /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test
n=1
for f in `ls -tr *.jpg`; do
  mv $f M$n.jpg
  n=$(( n + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: Nothing is happend. Don't u should specify the type of files?
e.g. *.h *.jpg

Comment: What did you try? What is the result? (There is no need to specify the suffix of the file: if not given, all files are shown.)

Comment: I would like to sort the jpg files by time&date first, after that I want to rename them like A1.jpg A2.jpg A3.jpg. Now I can rename the all files but I want to sort them from old to current before rename them.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question: please reformulate / update you initial question.

Comment: So sorry. Now I have the rename script like this:
cd /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/
n=1
for file in *.jpg; do
echo $file
prefix=M
file_name=M$n.jpg
echo $file_name
n=$(( $n+1 ))
mv $file $file_name
done

The first if I run script, the all of jpg files will be M1.jpg M2.jpg M3.jpg but if I add the new file name A1.jpg to this directory and run script again. All of M1.jpg M2.jpg M3.jpg will be replaced by M4.jpg(before run script was A1.jpg) because the first letter is A. It come before M. This is my problem. I would like to get M1 M2 M3 M4.jpg
Hope ypu understand that. Thank u for helping

Comment: @kantawit, you need to edit your question to add that information.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need to sort file paths in ascending order

```
ls -tUr -d $PWD/*
```

might be useful

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `-t` option to the `ls` command. The `-t` option sorts by time modified, i.e. the most recently modified first before sorting the operands by lexicographical order. In other words, last downloaded file can be displayed using the following command.

Open the Terminal and type the following command.

```
ls -t
```